# QBO API field names listing

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Does anyone know where to get a listing of API field names for the QBO API? I have recently discovered that the field names are different for the different currencies. For example, calling the API for a USD company to find Net Income would have a field name of Net Income versus calling the API for a CDN company would have a field name of PROFIT.

Is there a listing of field names somewhere for the various QBO API currency types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this available in their [API docs](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/account). It tends to be put under the expansion of what is available for multi-currency.

e.g.

```
MULTICURRENCY DISABLED
debit -> debt_amt
credit -> credit_amt 
currency -> N/A 
exchange rate -> N/A 
open balance -> nat_open_bal 
amount -> subt_nat_amount 
tax amount -> tax_amount 
taxable amount -> net_amount

MULTICURRENCY ENABLED 
debit -> debt_home_amt 
credit -> credit_home_amt 
currency -> currency 
exchange rate -> exch_rate 
open balance -> nat_home_open_bal 
amount -> subt_nat_home_amount 
tax amount -> home_tax_amount 
taxable amount -> home_net_amount
```